# Changing a dynamic table (based on the attributes of the Spring Model) using an AJAX call without reloading the page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Suppose I have the following code:

```
<div id="user-list">
    <div class="row" id="user-list-row">
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>${fn:escapeXml(user.firstName)}</li>
                    <li>${fn:escapeXml(user.lastName)}</li>
                    <li>${fn:escapeXml(user.email)}</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <a class="removeUserButton" user-id="${fn:escapeXml(user.id)}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

As you might understand from the code above, this is a plain dynamic table of users. Also, there is removing button. Having clicked it, the ajax call is being sent to the controller to delete the specific user from the database. So far so good for me, however, I also want to delete the user from the View. 
What I tried is to send another ajax call to get the most recent state of the Spring Model attributes representing users. 
Then I need to "repaint" the div with the user table. This approach didn't work for me (it loads the outdated table info): 
$("#user-list").load(location.href + " #user-list");

How can I make the browser present the updated user table with the most recent "userList" model on the View without updating the whole page but only the specified div?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information about the project, but I can see the problem and I can answer.

**What kind of information you should provide ?**

What technology you are using to generate the page in Java Spring world ? Jsp + JSTL ? Thymeleaf ? I can see that you are using JSTL because of `<c:forEach ...>` .

**Question answer**

You can't make the browser present the updated user table with the most recent "userList", because when you are making Ajax calls you are in a point that you can't control the userList anymore.

**Explenation**

No matter what view layer you are using (jsp or thymeleaf), even though both have different ways to generate the view, you can't control the userList object anymore. It's because of architecture flow of them.

**JSP Architecture Flow**

Take a look at this article: [JSP Architecture + Lifecycle](https://javabeat.net/jsp-architecture-lifecycle/)

> 1 - The user goes to a JSP page and makes the request via internet in
>   user’s web browser.
>
> 2 - The JSP request is sent to the Web Server.
>
> 3 - Web server accepts the requested .jsp file and passes the JSP file
>   to the JSP Servlet Engine.
>
> 4 - If the JSP file has been called the first time then the JSP file
>   is parsed otherwise servlet is instantiated. The next step is to
>   generate a servlet from the JSP file. The generated servlet output is
>   sent via the Internet form web server to users web browser.
>
> 5 - Now in last step, HTML results are displayed on the users web
>   browser.

So, when you are making an Ajax request, this whole process has already happened, it means that the object userList the JSP file was waiting has already been used to generated the servlet output, that is, the HTML displayed on the users web browser.

**So, what can you do?**

If you really need to show the updated user table with the most recent data, you need to reload the page, so this whole process will be done again.
But it isn't the the usually used solution for update a table with a deleted row. The usually used solution and simple one is just remove the HTML row after make the Ajax request.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation, Fabio.
I should've provided more details considering the workflow:
When we perform removing and there is no any user left, then the appropriate message is printed on the screen (so that there is no just a blank space). Hence, I need to perform another ajax call to the database and check whether there is any user left. If not, then change the div with the table with the appropriate message. That is not a problem

Comment: Another forgotten though important point: suppose, among all the existing users there must be one and only one 'boss' (boolean isBoss). So, there will be a button to set a user as a 'boss' in the future. When the 'boss' user gets deleted from the table with an ajax call, there must be at least someone in the table as a 'boss'. This logic will be implemented in the business layer. What I am trying to say is that when we delete the 'boss' we need to repaint the table - get the updated 'users info' with the new 'boss' set.

Comment: Currently, I am contemplating the approach where the controller would return the 'userList' in the JSON format. Then, I would analyze whether the JSON object is empty: if yes, then print the message, else - construct the table with the fetched object data from within JavaScript and then replace the needed table 'div' with it:
$( "div#users" ).replaceWith( repaintedTable);
Not sure if this is a good approach to render it within JavaScript manually, However, I cannot see other options now. 

This a TRAINING scenario I made up in my mind in order to practice, not a real project.

Comment: This approach would work, you could create a Javascript function called updateUserTable(), or something like that, and use this function to make an Ajax request, get the JSON object returned from your controller, and update a <div id="tableSpace"> ... </div> with the correct content. But it isn't the appropriete approach in JSP world.
Considering change the front-end stack for Angular for example, and use Java only for the back-end propose.
You are going to a SPA way, and JSP or Thymeleaf can't help you well.